# Can I add 'Export As' to an action script?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, photoshop-scripting, actions, script

Could somebody explain how I can add 'Export As' as an action script in Photoshop CC 2015?
I just want to automate saving icons to svg.

Answer (score 4):

Not quite sure that you can add that exact option to an action. But here's what you can do instead:

Go to `File -> Export -> Export Preferences` then change your preferences to something like this (you could make that part of your action too if you'll need to change this frequently):

[image]

Make sure `Quick Export Location` is set to `Export files to an assets folder next to the current document`

Now, record an action an when you're ready for the export go to `File -> Export -> Quick Export as SVG` and it will get added to your action.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for quick reply.
I just create [gif](http://recordit.co/I2hkuRXILI) animation that `File -> Export -> Quick Export as SVG` not recorded into my action.

Comment: Make sure that `Quick Export Location` is set to the second radio button, as in my screenshot and see if that works.

Comment: @ViktorTsarevskiy I edited my answer with my comment. That seemed to be the issue.

Comment: Does this create the multiple sizes `@1x, @.5x, etc`?  I can't seem to figure out how.

Comment: @JasonTFeatheringham I think you'd need to do these once yourself (as part of the action) and then you should be able to replay it later.

Comment: this has one huge problem, ifyou want to quick export say 100 images, you end up with 100 different directories - each in a dir with the file name with asset on the end.  that you cant specify a dir is a crippling limitation